# Стоит ли менять смысл слова “озвучить”

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как-то президент России Медведев сказал "озвучить" в значении "Иванов озвучил своё предложение". А не точнее ли будет, как встарь повелось: "Иванов ВЫСКАЗАЛ своё немудрящее предложение"? 
Вообще, вот такая АРГОментация языка не деструктурирует ли сознания его пользователей? Не приводит ли "к падению империй", как когда-то сокращение выражения "отнюдь нет" до "отнюдь"?
Не преступно ли искажение языка вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Грамота.ру критикует неуместное употребление глагола "озвучить". **В словарях не дается других значений слова, кроме терминологического.**

**ОЗВУЧИТЬ,** Проф. Произвести запись фонограммы к кинофильму (музыки, дикторского текста, шумов). О. фильм. О. старую киноленту.

[Озвучить | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_152)

В речи наших современников — и не только в обиходно-бытовой, но и в публичных выступлениях, в передачах радио и телевидения, т. е. в речи «на людях», предполагающей известную строгость, сдержанность в речевом поведении — и в манере вести разговор, в мимике, жестах, и (что особенно существенно!) в построении фраз, в выборе слов и выражений, **наблюдается приблизительность в выражении мысли, неточность в обозначении тех предметов, действий, о которых идет разговор, небрежность в обращении с падежами, в согласовании слов.** Иллюстрацией к сказанному может служить ставшее в последнее время очень распространенным употребления глагола **озвучить.**

В последние четыре-пять лет он получил распространение в речи политиков, парламентариев, журналистов в радио- и телепередачах. При этом глагол озвучить употребляется в контекстах, совершенно ему не свойственных и в смысле, далеком от его «кинематографического» происхождения.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**ОГЛАСИТЬ,** св. что. 1. Прочесть вслух для всеобщего сведения; объявить. Судья огласил приговор.  3. Наполнить громкими звуками (воздух, пространство).

**У  "озвучить" в значении "сообщить, объявить" есть достойный конкурент** ―  глагол огласить, между ними и разворачивается  борьба, пока счет 370:168 (во всех значениях) в пользу "огласить". Озвучить ―  совсем не плохая замена (или партнер в качестве синонима) для огласить.  Вторые значения отчасти похожи: наполнить **громкими** звуками пространство или сделать звуковым отснятый фильм.

**Поэтому добавят глаголу "озвучить" значение "сообщить", и таким образом зафиксируют реальное развитие языка.** Мне, по крайней мере, "озвучил" кажется не таким "громким", как огласил, а более нейтральным.

Сравнить: Люди бежали, падали. Пустыню **огласил** режущий вопль.  [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 2 (1960)]  Тут комнату с этим самым диваном **огласил** дикий рёв Никанора Ивановича, вскочившего с колен: [М. А. Булгаков]

Вчера прокурор **огласил** обвинительное заключение. В ноябре Центробанк **озвучил** среднюю максимальную ставку по депозитам.

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla. Ваш ответ, как всегда, подробен, но в вопросе звучит ещё и мысль о возможной реакции общества (сообщества) на последствия такого воздействия на Язык.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, как вы правильно заметили, *озвучить* в значении "высказать, сообщить" выглядит вычурно:

> ОЗВУ́ЧИТЬ, -чу, -чишь; сов., перех. (несов. озвучивать). Сделать звуковым (кинофильм).

Тем не менее подобные употребления очень часто встречаются в официально-деловой, или канцелярской, речи, и называются **канцеляризмами**. Стилистически, конечно, данный пример (*озвучить* 'высказать') выглядит ужасно, и его употребление вне официально-делового контекста приведет к **канцеляриту**, т. е. стилистической ошибке, связанной с неуместным употреблением канцелярского языка.

Корректно: *Иванов выразил / высказал / сообщил свое немудреное (немудрящий — просторечие) предложение*.

Не уверен, что это слово в таком значении приводит к какому-то там "деструктурированию сознания", но способствует проникновению канцеляризмов в нормальный лексикон так точно.

Байки травить я не буду — пусть этим займется кто-нибудь другой.

"Искажение языка" не преступно, потому что само по себе вздорно.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения. Хотел бы уточнить, почему это слово из технического лексикона называют канцеляризмом. Как в этот раздел попадают слова, или это просто общее название лексического стока? Слово "пользователь", здесь, в значении любое "лицо или организация, которое использует действующую систему для выполнения конкретной функции", а не только "спикер".

Comment: Да, и, разве влияния языка на развитие сознания не существует?

Comment: @Игорь само по себе *озвучить* 'сделать звуковым' не является канцеляризмом, а вот *озвучить* в значении 'высказать' — да. Канцеляризм — это слово или оборот речи, характерное для официально-делового стиля. Ну, как попадают... это уже отдельный вопрос, который требует тщательного исследования. Вот начинают часто использоваться в канцелярской речи — и попадают, а как — дело сложное, запутанное и требует частного подхода. Почитайте подробнее в Гугле, если интересно, или К. И. Чуковского "Живой как жизнь" и Н. Галь "Слово живое и мертвое".

Comment: @Игорь влияние языка на сознание — это научная тема, которая сейчас довольно активно исследуется. Более того, в ней совсем нет единства мнений и представлений, существует куча разных теорий и т. д., и т. п. Ну а, как понимаете, для нашего бытового вопроса все это поднимать и расписывать... дело неблагодарное.